# Is there a way to change the default notifications when making a new event in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

Whenever I create a new event, it defaults to including notifications 1 minute and 30 minutes prior to the event. I have to manually remove these if I don't want them. Is there a way to set the default new event to no notifications, so I can optionally add them when I want them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds similar to this: [How to Specify Default Reminders in Google Calendar](https://www.lifewire.com/specify-default-reminders-for-a-calendar-in-google-calendar-1172186)

The behavior here is as you describe. If the calendar has default reminders turned on, then all events that are created will have those notifications by default. You can then independently edit each event to remove the notifications, but that will not affect the default behavior.

tl;dr: Settings Gear > Settings > Calendar you want to edit on the left hand side > Event Notifications > remove anything that is present.